# Samba AD: Bind9 won't load DLZ library anymore

Tags: active-directory, bind, samba, domain-controller, arch-linux

I currently got a Problem with the Bind9 Backend on my Samba Domain Controller. Bind refuses to open the library Samba provides. But i can't figure out how to resolv this issu. Here is the SysLog:

```
  named[19939]: dlz_dlopen failed to open library '/usr/local/samba/lib/bind9/dlz_bind9_11.so' - /usr/lib/samba/libreplace-samba4.so: version `SAMBA_4.6.0PRE1_GIT_5F5BA89' not found (required by /usr/local/samba/lib/libsamba-util.so.0)
  named[19939]: dlz_dlopen of 'AD DNS Zone' failed
  named[19939]: SDLZ driver failed to load.
  named[19939]: DLZ driver failed to load.
  named[19939]: loading configuration: failure
  named[19939]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Samba Version:

```
samba -V
Version 4.6.0pre1-GIT-5f5ba89
```

Bind Version:

```
named -V
BIND 9.11.0-P1 <id:1e9bd53>
running on Linux armv7l 3.4.103 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 18 13:07:12 CST 2014
built by make with '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--sbindir=/usr/bin' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-static' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--enable-fixed-rrset' '--disable-seccomp' '--enable-full-report' '--with-python=/usr/bin/python' '--with-geoip' '--with-idn' '--with-openssl' '--with-libjson' '--with-libxml2' '--with-libtool' 'CFLAGS=-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
compiled by GCC 6.2.1 20160830
compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.4
linked to libxml2 version: 20904
compiled with libjson-c version: 0.12.1
linked to libjson-c version: 0.12.1
compiled with zlib version: 1.2.8
linked to zlib version: 1.2.8
threads support is enabled
```

Notice: This is running on Arch Linux and worked until the last System Update.

Answer (score 0):

I am setting up Samba4 AD on openSUSE Leap 42.1. I noticed this same issue and configured named to not chroot. Once I did that error went away.